# Azure AD authentication between applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have an application let's name it 'Apple' which is registered with Azure AD having delegated rights on Azure Management API application. When requested to this application it creates azure resource ex. storage account automatically and this works fine.

I have another application which is MVC application and it's also registered with same AD tenant. The second application uses following code for retrieving access token:

```
 var clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_ClientID"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_Client_AccessKey"]);
 var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_Tenant_Login_Url"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_Tenant_Id"]));            
 var result = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AD_Resource"], clientCredentials);
 if (result == null)
 {
     throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not get the token");
 }
 return result.Result;
```

The result is an access token having different properties. Now second application, retrives access token with access to resource apple, which it then passes to Apple application in authorization header.

```
Authorization:bearer TokenString
```

The Apple application is having Authorize attribute added to controller.
The application is configured with Owin with oauth application with following code

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {

                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                },
            });
    }
```

Please note that the access token is retrieved from second application using its own AppId and Secret key; whereas the other(Apple) application uses its own AppId and secret key for validating the token.

So my problem is, **the APPLE application always returns 401 not authorize code**

Comment: while I'm not receiving any reply, should I change tag, advise?

Comment: I am following this threads from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/af1f1ddc-649b-4b35-9e16-ced582380e6c/azure-ad-authentication-between-applications?forum=WindowsAzureAD), please let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: @Fei Xue, thank you for again catching me... I have replied to your answer...

Comment: Might be missing something, but why is the audience commented out? From what I understand the middleware will use both the audience and tenant to retrieve the public key to validate the signature of the token and when the signature is deemed invalid it will return a 401

Comment: @jimpaine we have moved quite further and we are on another problem to solve.. See here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/af1f1ddc-649b-4b35-9e16-ced582380e6c/azure-ad-authentication-between-applications?forum=WindowsAzureAD&prof=required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To above, question, the answer was, Resource ID (during token request) and Audience Id (during validation of token in second application) were not matching. Keeping those same solved the problem.

Then I ran into another issue, which I have described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/af1f1ddc-649b-4b35-9e16-ced582380e6c/azure-ad-authentication-between-applications?forum=WindowsAzureAD&prof=required)

It seems, If I work with newer Azure Portal (which is still in preview version), the `AD token` does not include `"Roles"` field in `JWT` token. If I follow same procedure in Older Portal for configuring apps, then AD includes `"Roles"` field in `JWT` token and scenario executes as expected.

**I should avoid using Azure new portal for preview features at least!**